# How do I code an standalone Athena API start_query_execution asynchronous call in Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm attempting to code an asynchronous API call to use **Athena** to run the action - `start_query_execution`. I am not using boto3 or any other library.

Any support on this query would be appreciated.

I've tried to change the following code by [Mathew Marcus](https://www.mathewmarcus.com/blog/asynchronous-aws-api-requests-with-asyncio.html), which uses the equivalent to the `lambda.invoke` using  what I am wanting to do. However, I have been unsuccessful in converting the code to an `athena.start_query_execution` instance.

SAMPLE OF MY CURRENT CODE:

```
request_parameters = '{'
request_parameters += 'QueryString: "SELECT * FROM <table_name> LIMIT 1;",'
request_parameters += 'ResultConfiguration: {"OutputLocation": "outputlocation"}'
request_parameters += '}'

creds = Session().get_credentials()
ATHENA_ENDPOINT_BASE = 'https://athena.{region}.amazonaws.com/'

def create_signed_headers(url, request_parameters):
    host_segments = urlparse(url).netloc.split('.')
    print('6. host_segments: ' , host_segments)
    service = host_segments[0]
    print('7. service: ' , service)
    region = host_segments[1]
    print('8. region: ' , region)
    request = AWSRequest(method ='POST',
                         url = url,
                         data=request_parameters)
    print('9. request: ', request)
    SigV4Auth(creds, service, region).add_auth(request)
    return dict(request.headers.items())

#query-string and result-configuration[output location] are *REQUIRED for start query execution

request_parameters

async def start_query_execution(url, request_parameters ,session):
    signed_headers = create_signed_headers(url, request_parameters)
    print('10. signed_headers: ' , signed_headers)
    async with session.post(url,
                            json = request_parameters,
                            headers = signed_headers) as response:
        return await response.json()

def generate_queries(name_and_request, base_url, session):
    for name, request_parameters in name_and_request:
        url = join(base_url, name, 'queries')
        print('5. url: ' , url)
        yield start_query_execution(url, request_parameters, session)

def start_all(name_and_request, region = 'eu-west-1'):
    base_url = ATHENA_ENDPOINT_BASE.format(region = region)
    print('3. base_url: ' , base_url)
    async def wrapped():
        async with ClientSession(raise_for_status=True) as session:
                queries = generate_queries(name_and_request,
                                                   base_url,
                                                   session)
                print('4. queries: ', queries)
                return await asyncio.gather(*queries)

    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(wrapped())

def main():
    name = 'hello-world-{}'
    name_and_request = ((name.format(i), dict(hello=i)) for i in range(10))
    print('1. name_and_request: ' , name_and_request)

    athena_responses = start_all(name_and_request)
    print('2. athena_responses: ', athena_responses)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think you need to provide at least some minimal context about what it is that is not working. Writing your own AWS client is a pretty big task, and anything could be wrong from request signing to spelling mistakes in the API calls. I would strongly urge you not to do it and just use boto3.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Theo, my initial attempts at finding solution did involve and still does involve using boto3, however there has been indications that boto3 does not support asynchronous calls within the context of the version of Python. Hence my attempt at using a direct call. As to providing context of what is not working, I agree there is not enough here. The reason for this is due to the fact that I could not isolate the exact origin of the error.